# Read lines and remove them after read complete

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python language, trying to develop a script to read a file with emails in it, split good emails from bad emails and than remove that line from the source file.
I got so far but here i have no idea how to remove the line already readed

Any help?

```
import os
with open('/home/klevin/Desktop/python_test/email.txt', 'rw+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #print line
        domain = line.split("@")[1]


        #print(domain)

        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + domain)


        if response == 0:
            print(response)
            file1 = open("good_emails.txt","a") 
            file1.write( line ) 

        else:
            print(response)
            file = open("bad_emails.txt","a") 
            file.write( line )
```

Comment: It's very difficult to make file updates in-place. Basically what you're going to need to do will require writing a new file while reading and copying data from the existing one except for skipping over anything you want removed (and write it to the "bad_emails" file instead).. Afterwards, you'll need to delete the previous version that was being read and rename the new one so it has the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would not prefer to both read and write to a file at the same time. So here is what I would do:

- open the file for reading
- loop over the emails and do your thing. In the comments below you've clarified you want to test only the first 100 mails, so that is what the code below now does.
- close the file
- reopen the file but this time in write mode, truncating it (throwing away its contents)
- write all the remaining (untested) emails to the file

This effectively removes all mails that have been tested.

The code might look like this:

```
import os

emails = []

# Opening the file for reading
with open('email.txt', 'r') as f, open("good_emails.txt", "w") as good, open("bad_emails.txt", "w") as bad:
    emails = f.readlines()

    # Only loop over the first 100 mails
    for line in emails[:100]:
        domain = line.split("@")[1]
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + domain)

        if response == 0:
            print(response)
            good.write( line ) 

        else:
            print(response)
            bad.write( line ) 

# Now re-open the file and overwrite it with the correct emails            
with open('email.txt', 'w') as f:
    # Write the remaining emails to the original file
    for e in emails[100:]:
        f.write(e)
```

Comment: Thank you, i tested now, it remove the bad emails from email.txt but it still keep the good emails, in this way when it will run again it will scan in loop the remaining emails. I need to remove from the original file bad and good emails.  Also i need to read and write because if the file will have millions of emails?

Comment: But if you remove both bad and good emails you will always be left with an empty file at the end...?

Comment: So my goal is this:
If i have 1000 emails and for the first cron it scan the first 100 emails, once finished in the list it will remain 900emails, when the second cron will run the process will start again and the email in the original list it will remain 800 emails and so on, till the list will be empty and the emails will be filtered in the bad or good email list.

Comment: I've changed the answer to take only the first 100 mails and check them, and write the rest of the file back, so effectively the first 100 lines are removed.

Comment: Can i ask a last question if possible? how to skip empty lines?

Comment: You can something like this: `if not line: continue`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's simply not how files work, you cannot just remove a couple lines from the middle of a file. To achieve what you want you want to overwrite or replace the file.

So in your code you'd remove the original file and copy `good_email.txt` over it:

```
import shutil
import subprocess

with open('email.txt', 'r') as original, open("good_emails.txt", "w") as good, open("bad_emails.txt", "w") as bad:
    for line in original:  # no need to readlines()
        domain = line.split("@")[1]
        response = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', domain])
        if response == 0:
            good.write(line) 
        else:
            bad.write(line)

shutil.copyfile('good_emails.txt', 'emails.txt')
```